# Exception TypeError: 'argument list must be a tuple'

Tags: python, c++, linker, typeerror, embedding

I am trying to call a simple python function from cpp.

Below is the cpp code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
using namespace std;

void init_numpy()
{
    import_array();
}

int main()
{
char dir[500];
cout << "Enter directory: \n";
cin >> dir;

Py_Initialize();

const char *scriptDirectoryName = dir; 
PyObject *sysPath = PySys_GetObject("path");
PyObject *path = PyString_FromString(scriptDirectoryName);
int result = PyList_Insert(sysPath, 0, path);
PyObject *pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("mytest");

init_numpy();
double getItem[2] ;

getItem[0] = getItem[1] = 2;

npy_intp dims = 2 ;

PyObject* arrayToPass =  PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, &dims, NPY_DOUBLE , (void *)getItem);

PyObject* myFunction = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule,(char*)"stuff");

//PyObject* args = PyTuple_Pack(1,PyFloat_FromDouble(getItem));
PyObject* myResult = PyObject_CallObject(myFunction, arrayToPass);
//double resultasd = PyFloat_AsDouble(myResult);
//cout << resultasd << endl;

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my python code:
mytest.py

```
def stuff(a):
   x = a[1]
   return x
```

This just testing of a bigger patch I am writing, but the methodology is the same.

I am getting this error:

```
Exception TypeError: 'argument list must be a tuple' in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

I searched multiple threads but everyone had a unique typo or a bug.

Any suggestions where I am doing wrong?

I am compiling as:

```
g++ -I /usr/include/python2.7/   che.cpp -lpython2.7 -o linkArr
```

Comment: Can anyone give at least a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation:

> PyObject* PyObject_CallObject(PyObject *callable, PyObject *args)
>   Return value: New reference.
>   Call a callable Python object callable, with arguments given by the tuple args. If no arguments are needed, then args can be NULL.

Return the result of the call on success, or raise an exception and return NULL on failure.

This is the equivalent of the Python expression: callable(*args).

The function PyObject_CallObject(...)  requires tuple as an argument.

Also checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60487083/passing-array-tuple-from-python-back-to-c)   and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804623/c-to-numpy-and-back-to-c-tuple-pyobject) for more clarification.